# Lua table indexing issues between strings and integers

Tags: lua

I created a complex table of tables and used a variable as the indexes. For some reason I had issues with my code being very buggy.

It turned out that I have to convert the index to strings

So

```
myTable[index]
```

needed to become

```
myTable[tostring(index)]
```

else

Sometimes index would act as a string and other times it would act as an integer(I never converted index to a string in any point in the code though.

This caused problems because `myTable[1]` and `myTable["1"]` would be created and both would be different(and I was looping over the k/v pairs and so `myTable[1]` wouldn't show up).

This is very strange behavior but I guess is expected? Is there any way to create a new type based on a table that always uses string indexes so this kidna stuff could be avoided?

Answer (score 6):

Lua automatically coerces between strings and numbers, depending on the context where they are used (see the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.2) and this [wiki page](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Coercion)).

It seems that somewhere along the way, you read in the index either from a file, or you use string concatenation operator `..`, and it becomes a string. To me it seems that you want to use only numeric indexes.

To make sure that `index` stays a number, use `tonumber()` after any processing or reading from a file - `index = tonumber(index)`. In Lua table's view, `1` and `"1"` are different keys.